# How do I find the Server Data Type for a given field while using LINQ to SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm using LINQ to SQL in a .NET project, and I'm trying to do some specific property when a field is of type money.  The SQL Type Money will map to the .NET type Decimal, but so will other types such as Decimal.  Short of looking up in the SYS_COLUMN table, is there any way I can determine at runtime what the SQL Server Type is for a given field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Reflection on the `Type`.

```
use System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

var dbType = ((ColumnAttribute)typeof(dbclass).GetField("fieldname").GetCustomAttribute(typeof(ColumnAttribute))).DbType;
```